# PostgreSQL 9.4 Updating rule on joined view with conflict on unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, qgis

I have a view composed of few tables, so in order to make it updatable I created a rule. Everything works fine except that I have a UNIQUE field, and sometime I have two objects which are inversed on that field. So when I try to launch an update query on my view to correct it, I get an error saying that the value is already taken.

I guess an important parameter is that I am using a third-party software to access and edit my database (QGIS), so the UPDATE queries I am launching are generally made by a batch process.

My rule is simply defined as such:

```
CREATE RULE _update AS ON UPDATE TO view DO INSTEAD UPDATE etc...
```

The way I understand it the rule works row by row, so when it tries to apply for the first row it raises an error because obviously the value is already taken (as long as the other row has not been updated). Is that right?

I am guessing it is a pretty common situation, but I cannot figure out how to solve it, and since I am not a native english speaker, neither can I find with which terms search online.

What is the way to solve that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the unique index as `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` it will not be checked until the end of the transaction rather than checking it for each updated row.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. One detail though, the constraint needs to be INITIALLY DEFERRED in order for it to work.